# Eclipse autocompletion for jdk.* packages does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I write here because I noticed a strange behaviour of Eclipse IDE (2022-12).

Basically, the autocompletition does not work properly when I use a class from a `jdk.*` package.

For example:

```java
import jdk.jshell.*;
public class Test {
private static final JShell JSHELL = JShell.create();
...
...
public static void main(String[] args) {} 

}
```

Now when I write `JSHELL.` (e.g., inside the main method), I get only proposal for the methods of the `Object` class. No specific proposal is available.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Tried updating & reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: `jdk.*` is filtered by default. Does in the preferences _Java > Appearance > Type Filters_ unchecking `jdk.*` work for you?

Comment: Oh, thanks! It was checked, I unchecked it and now it works. Didn't know about this "filter" of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jdk.*` is filtered by default.

When you want to use something of `jdk.*` in a project, go to the **preferences *Java > Appearance > Type Filters*** and **uncheck** the item **`jdk.*`**.